# How to do a batch commit in plpgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I do the below function, some errors occurs:

```
**ddddl=# select sssss(1,10);
ERROR:  cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL
HINT:  Use a BEGIN block with an EXCEPTION clause instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sssss(integer,integer) line 8 at SQL statement**
```

Here is my sample code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sssss(
IN c_1 int,
IN f_i int
) returns void as
$$
    DECLARE t_c     INT;
    BEGIN
        t_c := f_i;
        WHILE c_1 <= t_c
            loop
            IF MOD(c_1, 4) = 1 THEN
                start transaction;
            END IF;
            -- My statements here.
            IF MOD(c_1, 4) = 0 THEN
                COMMIT;
            END IF;
            c_1 := c_1 + 1;
        END loop;
        COMMIT;
    END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

So could anyone give me a sample of how to finish my job as the above code?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve with this batching? If you're trying to improve performance, then you should generally rephrase the whole thing not to rely on a PL/PgSQL `LOOP` in the first place - use normal set operations instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I think there are three approaches you can take:

- Do without. Just let the whole thing be committed at once, like PostgreSQL wants.
- Write a wrapper in application code that sets up a transaction and calls your function. (This is simple to do in a shell script, for example.)
- Use a hack. One hack that exists is, you can have your function create a database-link to your own database, and perform subtransactions via remote sessions. [[More information.](http://raghavt.blogspot.com/2012/05/autonomous-transaction-in-postgresql-91.html)] (This is essentially equivalent to the "wrapper in application code" approach, except that the application code is still in PL/pgSQL.)

Answer (score 3):

From Postgresql 12 onwards you can do batch commits if you use procedures instead of functions, invoked by CALL command. Therefore you're function will be rewritten like below and invoked with CALL command:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sssss(IN c_1 int,IN f_i int) 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    DECLARE 
      t_c     INT;
    BEGIN
            t_c := f_i;
            WHILE c_1 <= t_c
                loop
                -- My statements here.
                IF MOD(c_1, 4) = 0 THEN
                    COMMIT;
                END IF;
                c_1 := c_1 + 1;
            END loop;
            COMMIT;
        END;
    $$;

    CALL sssss(1,10);
```

More details about transaction management regarding Postgres are available here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html